# How can I return values from this NodeJS request function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I am trying to make an API call using NodeJS. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to grab the object from inside the JS function so I can parse for attributes and store as a variable in the main function. I understand that I am calling a function within a function (inline asyncronous) How would I grab the myData object from this functionn?

```
var request = require('request')

function getData(URL){
    var url = URL; 
    request('http://api.smmry.com?SM_API_KEY=APIKEYHERE&SM_URL=' + URL, function (error, response, body) { 

    var myData = new Object();
    myData = JSON.parse(body); //We need to turn this into an object in order to grab its attributes.
    return myData;
    });
}


 console.log(getData('http://www.cnn.com/2017/07/16/politics/mark-warner-jay-sekulow-donald-trump-jr/index.html'))
```

Thank you.

Comment: You must understand node callback concept first.

Comment: and promises. and async / await

Comment: Then answer is "you wouldn't". You can't return the result of an asynchronous function, you have to work with the result *inside* the callback.

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares Is there an existing Question addressing the present inquiry specifically as to `node.js`?

Comment: Not specifically to node, but the first answer of that question explores everything OP needs to solve his problem. It presents promises, async/await, callbacks, etc.